# HTML5 canvas anti-alias?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a quadratic curve with canvas. Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<canvas id="mycanvas"> 
    Your browser is not supported.
</canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
canvas.style.width = "1000px";
canvas.style.height = "1000px";
if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x = 0,
        y = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();
        x += 1;
        y = 0.01 * x * x;
    }, 100);
}
```

But the result is really ugly, first, the lines are too thick, second, the alias is so obvious.... how could I improve it?
You can see the effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/7wNmx/1/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you're doing is creating a canvas which is the default size, 300 by 150, and then scaling it up using CSS to 1000px by 1000px. But scaling it up like that just magnifies the size of the pixels, it doesn't increase the resolution of the canvas itself. What you need to do is set the actual dimensions of the canvas itself using the `width` and `height` attributes:

```
<canvas width="1000" height="1000" id="mycanvas"> 
    Your browser is not supported.
</canvas>
```

Then you don't need to scale it up by setting `canvas.style.width` and `height` any more.

Comment: It's still not pretty. A bezier curve might be useful (animation would be different): http://www.robodesign.ro/coding/canvas-primer/20081208/example-paths.html

Comment: This solved the resizing with CSS issue, though my project required relative sizing within the canvas container div rather than hard coding pixel sizes. The following question helped with sizing by percent: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18679414/9403538

Answer (score 24):

Another thing is that you're stroking *each* time. So the first line is drawn most, whilst the second is drawn one less time, etc.

This also causes it to become ugly. You'd need to begin a new path and only stroke that one:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
canvas.style.width = "1000px";
canvas.style.height = "1000px";
if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x = 0,
        y = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x,y)
        x += 1;
        y = 0.01 * x * x;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }, 100);
}
```

Compare:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/40M20.png]

It's also faster since less drawing is done.

Comment: Yep, this is another issue. Good catch! Between our two answers, it looks a lot better.