# HTML5 Canvas stroke not anti-aliased

Tags: html5-canvas, antialiasing, stroke

I'm just trying to make a circle with a thick anti-aliased stroke in canvas.

The circle gets drawn as expected, but the edges of the stroke are very jaggy. I keep reading that Chrome forces anti-aliasing, so not sure what to do...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nipponese/hWsxw/

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border: 1px solid #000"></canvas>
        <div id="counter" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid #000">
     </div>
</div>
```

**The JS + jQuery**

```
<script>
    function calc(myVal) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var radius = 70;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(140, 140, 20, myVal * Math.PI, 0, true);
        ctx.lineWidth = 14;
        ctx.stroke();
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var count = 0;
        var parsedCount;
        function go(){  
            if (count <= 200) {
                parsedCount = count*.01
                $('#counter').html('<p>' + parsedCount + '</p>');
                calc(parsedCount);
                count++;
            }
        }
        setInterval(go, 10)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 canvas anti-alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032263/html5-canvas-anti-alias)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My co-worker just pointed out that I need to use clearRect to clear the canvas after each draw. The strokes were just being drawn on top of each other.

```
function calc(myVal) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var radius = 70;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(140, 140, 20, myVal * Math.PI, 0, true);
    ctx.lineWidth = 14;
    ctx.stroke();
};
```