# How can I make my HTML5 canvas arc less pixellated, or more anti-aliased?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The following arc is drawn in HTML5 canvas. How can I make the outside of the arc smoother and less pixelated, or more anti-aliased?

[image: an arc drawn in html5 canvas]

#### This is the code used to create the arc above

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 100;
var startAngle = Math.PI;
var endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
var counterClockwise = false;
var outX = x
var outY = y
var vari1 = .1;
var endAngle = startAngle + vari1 * Math.PI;
context.beginPath();
context.arc(outX, outY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
context.lineWidth = 25;
context.strokeStyle = '#FA603D';
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I don't see where is the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/eu6uK/

Comment: look at the top of the arc and u can see its not smooth . that is the problem . and i need to know if there is any way to make it smooth without a grain effect on outside

Comment: It's already anti-aliased on my browser: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9jXHx.png (both Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: I didn't see any problem either... By the way your code is fairly standard in html5. I think one of your problem may be css style. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032263/html5-canvas-anti-alias. If your canvas is scaled up by css, it does not acquire additional pixel and thus gets resolution quality down.

Comment: used  context.lineCap = 'round'; and context . shadowBlur [ = value ] but it will give only little effects and only at the end of the arc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas stroke not anti-aliased](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164780/html5-canvas-stroke-not-anti-aliased)

Comment: @user719662 I don't think that dupe is related to this--that's a repeated drawing while this is one-shot, unless OP isn't showing all of their code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can short of using a retina display (not trying to be sarcastic).

You can give the illusion of more smoothness by having less contrast between the arc and the background.

If you were drawing lines rather than arcs, you could turn off anti-aliasing in Chrome to make the lines sharper.

Comment: is there any programatic way to make arc smoother.  (we cannot expect some one to use higher resolution systems  right)

Comment: Not that I've found--and I've looked mightily.  The arc highlights the sins of rectangular pixels used on computer monitors.  It's like the old phrase "can't put a round peg in a square hole".  If it fits your design, you might seriously consider using less contrasting colors for your arc and background.  Alternatively, a solid black background fools the eye into seeing a smoother orange arc--hence the popularity of darker or black background sites.  Sorry, I don't think there's a good solution out there for your situation.