# Particles.js, How to make the hight of canvas holding the animating particles, span across its parent element on small screens

Tags: html, vue.js, canvas, particles.js

I am trying to use particles.js, I never used the HTML5 canvas before honestly,  I just need a fast fix for now, so I am using a library called [vue-particles](https://vue-particles.netlify.com/) for an easy integration and usage of particles.js in a Vue.js application, I got it up and running perfectly fine, the issue arises when I decrease the screen width, so on my laptop screen that is `1364px wide` and above, there are no issues, when it goes down to tablets and mobile screen sizes, the canvas covers only 50% of the height of its parent component, I tried targeting the canvas element and adjusting its height to 100%, but it either doesn't work at all, or it covers the entire page instead of its parent element only. so I would appreciate if someone help me out with that.

this is how I used it in my .vue component

```
<template>
 <div class="parent">
  <div id="particles">
   <vue-particles color="dedede" :particlesNumber="40"></vue-particles>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

If you need further code or information to clarify the issue, Please leave it in a comment below,

thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as i know, canvas size must be set in pixels, perhaps you should resize your canvas manually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679414/how-put-percentage-width-into-html-canvas-no-css

Comment: Yeah man that worked with some media queries, thanks a lot :)