# Css, width 100% is much smaller than 500px when my screen is 1700px wide

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a reponsive layout for the 3-d globe, I've stored it like this:

```
  <div class="text-center main">
      <canvas id='globe' width='100%' height='100%'></canvas>
  </div>
```

however, when I give fixed width and height of 700px it will display size I want on my screen. However, I want to make it responsive therefore when displayed on cell phones the globe does not break and instead gets smaller. Can someone explain why 100% is smaller than 500px and simply increasing percentage to 200 ~300 % fixes the problem?

Comment: Set the div size to 100% also, instead of just the canvas, as the canvas is the child element, it'll have boundaries set by its parent element

Comment: I am setting both canvas and div to width and height of 100% and it will not show full globe. I can increase div height using px however I want to make it responsive.

Comment: have you tried 100vw and 100vh?

Answer (score 1):

(Codepen: http://jsfiddle.net/hmen49yj/ )

You CAN'T use percent in width and height attributes on canvas element.

you CAN'T use `css` as well, because it will scale the canvas. instead you should use `javascript` to set canvas size relative to it's container, at start and resize:

```
function resized(){
    var canvas = $('#globe');
    canvas.width(canvas.parent().width() );
    canvas.height(canvas.parent().height() );
}
resized();
$("body")[0].onresize = resized;
```

Comment: I've used second code and increased % to 700 and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @makewhite as i said, chrome will ignore % and consider it px. so your basically using 700px. not sure about other browsers.

Comment: oh but when I use percentage the full globe is not showing instead it is zoomed in very much.

Comment: @makewhite oops, it seems that css percentage will scale the canvas. you should use js to set canvas size as it described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18680851/4718434

Comment: @makewhite something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hmen49yj/

Comment: @makewhite answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to you use this way ...

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
    *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0
    }
    .main{
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100vh;
        background: green;
    }
    #globe{
        position:relative;

        width:70%;
        height:20vh;
        background: red;
    }
    .text-center{
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="text-center main">
    <canvas id='globe'></canvas>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```